# Laravel - React blocked by CORS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cors

I've laravel application, it works well with postman.
And I've created a React project as well.

I am trying to generate a token with laravelproject.com/oauth/token endpoint.

But when I send request, it returns error like that:

`from origin 'http://localhost:3011' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This is my Cors.php file in middelware and I've added to Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response) $next
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', ' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', ' true');
    }
}
```

And here's my react request below:

```
return axios.post<AuthModel>(LOGIN_URL, {
    username: email,
    password,
    business: reference,
    "grant_type": "password"
  },{
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
  })
```

I tried to remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', line, nothing changes. I removed all headers also, not worked.

In the internet, that CORS policy is the most mysterious topic i guess. It works in some cases, doesnt work in another cases. Whats common point? I dont know.

Comment: Your middleware does tno seem to be running at all. The headers are not there. Laravel has [built-in CORS middleware you](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors) you should use and from experience that seems to work if properly set-up. The documentation of it is a bit lacking but I think it needs to be added in the global kernel middleware as well as on the specific route you want to allow CORS on. Your current setup will not work even if the middleware runs because Allow-Origin cannot be `*` if you also allow credentials (the laravel middleware can handle this too)